# mediaserverd causes memory warning

Tags: ios, memory, avaudioplayer

my app continuously gets memory warnings and crashes after a couple of debug sessions, because `mediaserverd` is using up to `285 MB real memory` and `359 MB virtual memory`. During the first debug session it uses `9 MB real memory` and `77 MB virtual memory`.

The app plays audiobooks from the media library using an `AVAudioPlayer` object.

Is there any way to keep `mediaserverd's` memory footprint small?

Comment: I think there are memory leaks in your app. 
Question 1: If your app enter background, will mediaserverd's memory go back to normal state? 
Question 2: Can you share your code?